# Powershell: Executing Base64 commands returns error?

Tags: powershell

I need help with a simple test case of executing a CLI command through PowerShell which has already been encoded in Base64.

Suppose `Get-ChildItem` has been converted in advance to Base64 string `R2V0LUNoaWxkSXRlbQ==`.

Further suppose I have a DOS CLI instance open, and I want to test executing this string in powershell:

```
C:>\ powershell.exe -enc R2V0LUNoaWxkSXRlbQ==
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
The term '???????' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. 
At line:1 char:8
*??????? <<<<
    + CategoryInfo        :ObjectNotFound: (???????:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorID: CommandNotFoundException
```

I understand there's a way that works which introduces the use of variables, and even includes the encoding process itself. But what I want to know is, is this method salvageable? What might I be doing wrong?  I'm running PS version 2.0 in Win7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it must be encoded, use the following to get your Base64 string:

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes('Get-ChildItem'))
```

Trying this worked for me:

```
powershell.exe -encodedCommand RwBlAHQALQBDAGgAaQBsAGQASQB0AGUAbQA=
```

Comment: On a side note, I did notice that a website that offers Base64 encoding provided the incorrect string you were using. I would avoid encoding my Base64 string using such methods and stick to the encoding functions provided in the tool you intend to use them with.

Comment: it's because those websites use UTF-8 whereas PowerShell only accepts UTF-16 encoded string[

Answer (score 4):

To add to @SomethingElse's answer, the difference between your Base64 string that doesn't work, and their Base64 string that does work, is the character encoding used when converting the original string to byte values.

It needs to be encoded as UTF-16-LE, then converted to Base64 for PowerShell to like it, and yours was encoded as UTF8/plain ASCII.

```
# Your version, with 1-byte-per-character encoding:
PS> [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('Get-ChildItem'))
R2V0LUNoaWxkSXRlbQ==

# Working version, with 2-bytes-per-character encoding:
PS> [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes('Get-ChildItem'))
RwBlAHQALQBDAGgAaQBsAGQASQB0AGUAbQA=
```

Answer (score 1):

The character encoding used by `powershell` is `UTF-16LE`.

So if you're encoding your string from a **Linux** based OS, you can use `iconv` to make the output compatible with `powershell`:

```sh
$ printf 'whoami' | iconv -t UTF-16LE | base64
dwBoAG8AYQBtAGkA
$ powershell -EncodedCommand 'dwBoAG8AYQBtAGkA'
user1
```